# Java Cipher suite

Tags: java, ssl, encryption

I wrote a code to generate the cipher suites of a server.I am getting an output of the form `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA`.

Is there an API which can give me the cipher suite in parsed form like output in form of. Assymetric algorithm used RSA,Symmetric Algorithm used AES,Key size=128,Hashing algo is SHA?. I could have  written a parser to parse the output,but the output not always follow the same format like sometimes the key size is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the Java cipher suite naming patterns follow the TLS specification naming patterns, which don't give an easy way to extract this information from the name. For example, even the table in [TLS 1.1 Appendix C](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4346#appendix-C) doesn't indicate the key size for `AES_128_CBC` (it is in the table of the [TLS 1.2 spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#appendix-C)). This information comes from the [AES cipher suites specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3268).

Extracting these details is usually done semi-manually. See example implementation in Apache Tomcat's [`JSSESupport`](http://geronimo.apache.org/maven/external/catalina/6.0.20.0/catalina/xref/org/apache/tomcat/util/net/jsse/JSSESupport.html) (e.g. `getKeySize`) and [`SSLSupport`](http://geronimo.apache.org/maven/external/catalina/6.0.20.0/catalina/xref/org/apache/tomcat/util/net/SSLSupport.html).